# Capture output response code of cloudformation update command

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am writing a shell script which will update a stack if it exists. However, if there are no changes the stack updation is failing with an error:

> An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the UpdateStack operation: No updates are to be performed.

My commands are

```
aws cloudformation update-stack --stack-name . . .
aws cloudformation wait stack-update-complete . . .
```

If `update-stack` throws the above `ValidationError`, the next statement for `wait` hangs forever or quite a long period.

To get around this problem, I would like to capture output response or code of `aws cloudformation update-stack --stack-name . . .` in a variable and check this value or code for any error. If there is any error then don't execute `wait` command.

I have tried this but no luck:

```
OUTPUT="$(aws cloudformation update-stack --stack-name . . .)"
echo "${OUTPUT}"
```

Comment: This isn't really a question about cloudformation then, but rather about scripting - you want to execute one command, and then conditionally execute another command based on the exit code of the previous command. So put some relevant scripting tags in there.

Comment: That's correct. However, value in OUTPUT variable is always empty. This command is not writing output to the variable and printing it to console.

Comment: It has definitely to do with the way cloudformation is handling update-stack calls.